# PHP checkbox display and update

Tags: php, html

Good day!
While bowsing, I receive notice- "Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in file.php on line 52". Below is the code:

```
<?php
//check for any errors
if(isset($error)){
    foreach($error as $error){
        echo $error.'<br />';
    }
}
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postCont FROM blog_posts_seo WHERE postID = :postID') ;
        $stmt->execute(array(':postID' => $_GET['id']));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
<form action='' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='postID' value='<?php echo $row['postID'];?>'>
    <p><label>Title</label><br />
    <input type='text' name='postTitle' value='<?php echo $row['postTitle'];?>'></p>
    <p><label>Description</label><br />
    <textarea name='postDesc' cols='60' rows='10'><?php echo $row['postDesc'];?></textarea></p>
    <p><label>Content</label><br />
    <textarea name='postCont' cols='60' rows='10'><?php echo $row['postCont'];?></textarea></p>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Categories</legend>
        <?php
        $stmt2 = $db->query('SELECT catID, catTitle FROM blog_cats ORDER BY catTitle');
        while($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()){
        $stmt3 = $db->prepare('SELECT catID FROM blog_post_cats WHERE catID = :catID AND postID = :postID') ;
        $stmt3->execute(array(':catID' => $row2['catID'], ':postID' => $row['postID']));
            $row3 = $stmt3->fetch(); 
        if($row3['catID'] == $row2['catID']){
            $checked = 'checked';
        } else {
            $checked = null;
        }
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='catID[]' value='".$row2['catID']."' $checked> ".$row2['catTitle']."<br />";
        }
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update'></p>
</form>
```

Co-operation is highly appreciated

Best regards,

Comment: Try to change `while($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()){`  to `while($row2 = $stmt2->fetch_array()){`

Comment: it seems you are accessing`$row` or `$row2` or `$row3` and one of them is FALSE (because `fetch` did not return any row). I guess this may be `$row3`, as you fetch a row, but didn't test if one is returned. Please be kind enough to do some minimal debug before posting here. By the way, if you had told us which line is n°52, this would be more convenient

Comment: Thanks for response.

This is line 52:   if($row3['catID'] == $row2['catID']){

Comment: @Simone Rossaini
After changing 'while($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()){ to while($row2 = $stmt2->fetch_array()){ ' I am receiving following error. 

Please advise. Thanks in advance....

Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_array() in edit-post.php:146 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in edit-post.php on line 146

Comment: $stmt2->fetch() TO $stmt2->fetchAll();  Try that

Comment: Dear Mr. Simone Rossaini, Many thanks for your response. The change causing display following notices:

Notice: Undefined index: catID in edit-post.php on line 149

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in edit-post.php on line 152
Notice: Undefined index: catID in edit-post.php on line 152
Notice: Undefined index: catID in edit-post.php on line 158
Notice: Undefined index: catTitle in edit-post.php on line 158

Thanks in advance for your kind response.